# angular resolve with nested promise and observable

Tags: angular

I am using resolve with routing in one component but in resolve, one HTTP call is dependent on other Promise call.

```
resolve(){
  return this.storage.getUser().then( user => {
    this.getVendorDetails(user.login);
  });
}

getVendorDetails(loginId) {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/getVendor/' + loginId);
}
```

In component when I am trying to get the data from `ActivatedRoute`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe( data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I am getting `undefined`. Maybe I'm missing something in the resolve function.
How can I get the `getVendorDetails()` response into `ngOnInit()` using `ActivatedRoute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make one an observabe, or the other one a promise and always return this:

```
resolve() {
  return this.storage.getUser().then(user => this.getVendorDetails(user.login).toPromise());
}
```

or

```
resolve() {
  return from(this.storage.getUser()).pipe(
    switchMap((user) => this.getVendorDetails(user.login))
  );
}
```